# How to say "sublease" if it is not about real estate

Tags: word-choice

If I rent a house and lease it to another person, it's called "sublease".

Then how can I say if it it not about real estate?
For example a company rent money from a bank, and lend it to another company or person.

Can I also use the verb "sublease"?

Comment: This is really a financial question requiring expert knowledge of financial markets and not the sort of information useful to learners of everyday English.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "rent stocks from a bank". Do you mean "borrow money from a bank"?

Comment: @TRomano Sorry, my mistake. It's not from a bank but a organization or individual. But as Chris said that not a question English itself and "borrow money from a bank" is better as an example. How can I say it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial party **borrows** money from a bank.
You can say the money was **reloaned** to another party.  Which frames *what* was done and *how* it was done.  You could also say the money was **passed through** the second intermediary, but that has a different meaning to a loan.

In renting there is the **lessor** and then possibly a **sublease** and a **sub-sublease**.  In borrowing money there is no **sub-borrower**  eventhough circumstances effecting the **sub-borrower** will cascade up the chain just as circumstances effecting a **sub-sublessor** may cascade up the chain.

In financial markets if a market (buy/sell) is made after the **primary** participant, the mechanism is called the **secondary market**.  For example, participants in an IPO would be considered **primaries**, then the open stock market is considered the **secondary market**.